# How deploy a GWT project into OSGi container?

Tags: gwt, osgi

I have developed a simple GWT application with the client/server packages. From server package only dispatches the calls to other bundle. However, now I am at production time and I need to deploy the project into OSGi container like Felix. By this reason I would like to know if someone could tell me what are the steps that I need to follow???

Thanks in advance!

Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with declarative services on Equinox. The GWT runs!!!!

Comment: Could you please extend on your answer?

Comment: I followed this link: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97690.rhtml I hope it would be useful!!